# Salvar Dados JS no DB

Tags: php, javascript, geolocalização, cakephp-3

Eu to precisando salvar um valor de uma Variavel JS no Banco de Dados, porém não tenho nem ideia de como fazer.
Eu tenho uma pagina que captura  a localização do usuário , essa localização vem como um objeto javascript, e eu não tenho ideia de como fazer para salvar no DB.^
Minha aplicação esta sendo desenvolvida em cima do CAKEPHP 3.
Grato.

// Note: This example requires that you consent to location sharing when
      // prompted by your browser. If you see the error "The Geolocation service
      // failed.", it means you probably did not give permission for the browser to
      // locate you.
      var map, infoWindow;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 6
        });
        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
        // Try HTML5 geolocation.
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            };

```
        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
        infoWindow.open(map);
        map.setCenter(pos);
      }, function() {
        handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
      });
    } else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }
  }

  function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                          'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                          'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
    infoWindow.open(map);
  }
</script>
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=YourKEY&callback=initMap"
```

A Variavel em questão é a var pos;

Answer (score 0):

Tente disparar uma requisição ajax para uma página que só faz salvar o dado no banco.
Acredito que seja a melhor forma de se resolver o problema.

Talvez [isso aqui](https://www.blogson.com.br/como-gravar-dados-no-banco-de-dados-usando-ajax/) possa te ajudar.